# CSP Scanner: Wildcard Directive alert for OpenID Connect session management endpoint

Tags: identityserver4, openid-connect, content-security-policy, zap

We used ZAP 2.8 to scan our angular web application implemented with IdentityServer4 (implicit flow).

It generated a Wildcard Directive alert (show in below), I am not sure it is a security issue or not.

If it is a security issue, what should we do?  The OpenID Connect session management endpoint is not part of our app, it is IdentityServer4 build-in functionality. any suggestions? thanks

---

Medium (Medium) CSP Scanner: Wildcard Directive
Description 
The following directives either allow wildcard sources (or ancestors), are not defined, or are overly broadly defined:frame-ancestor

URL https://server103.abc.com:54231/services.identity/connect/checksession

Method  GET

Parameter   Content-Security-Policy

Evidence    default-src 'none'; script-src 'sha256-ZT3q7lL9GXNGhPTB1Vvrvds2xw/kOV0zoeok2tiV23I='

Comment: Is the listed evidence your entire CSP?

Comment: hi @kingthorin  yes , it is entire CSP.  thanks.  

`content-security-policy: default-src 'none'; script-src 'sha256-ZT3q7lL9GXNGhPTB1Vvrvds2xw/kOV0zoeok2tiV23I='


x-content-security-policy: default-src 'none'; script-src 'sha256-ZT3q7lL9GXNGhPTB1Vvrvds2xw/kOV0zoeok2tiV23I='  `

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that the `frame-ancestors` isn't defined.
Per: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors

> default-src fallback  No. Not setting this allows anything.

So even though you did define `default-src`, `frame-ancestors` doesn't fallback to it, so since it's unspecified it'll accept anything.

It's up to you (or whoever controls the other component) if that's an issue or not.

Comment: This didn't work for me when i used `frame-ancestor`, but it did when I use `frame-ancestors`. See https://content-security-policy.com/

Comment: Yup that was a typo, it's been fixed in the scan rule.